# Handling properties/configurations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, properties, environment-variables

I want to be able to move hard-coded configuration outside of my .rb files.

I don't want to have stuff like this:

```
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
       :host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   }
```

I need it to be easy to change between different machines.
What will be the best path to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually configuration stuff is intended to stay inside .rb files -- that's the best path to achieve different configurations in different environments.

So if you have a production environment and a beta environment, in beta.rb you'd have:

```
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
       :host => 'beta.mydomain.com',
   }
```

And in production.rb you'd have:

```
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
       :host => 'www.mydomain.com',
   }
```

If you're trying to store your configuration settings elsewhere, you're probably trying to vary the settings because your deployment environment isn't static (like EC2, where you could be bringing up and down machines constantly with different IPs). In that case, I'd recommend investigating a tool like [rubber](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber) or [chef](https://github.com/opscode/chef) that provide programmatic ways to transform configuration files.